# List embedded Instagram posts on Ionic 3 page

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, ionic3, instagram-api

I want to list embedded Instagram posts inside my Ionic 3 app. I tried doing it manually:
1. Went to Instagram on my desktop, chose a public post and clicked on the three dots on the embed option. I copied the link and pasted it inside my page:

```
<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-permalink="https://www.instagram.com/p/Bmoikg2ABAt/?utm_source=ig_embed" data-instgrm-version="9" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:540px; min-width:326px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50.0% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5/P8/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div> <p style=" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/Bmoikg2ABAt/?utm_source=ig_embed" style=" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;" target="_blank">And lastly, my actual #1 @courtneyjbarry you are an incredible woman. The way you handle life’s most confusing moments is indescribable and graceful. You are moved by the littlest stories to the most heartbreaking ones, you will give someone your perfume if they say you smell nice, you are freaking hilarious and always stand firm in your faith, a loving sister, an amazing friend and a beautiful daughter. You are the definition of FEARFULLY and WONDERFULLY made baby! #1</a></p> <p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">A post shared by <a href="https://www.instagram.com/selenagomez/?utm_source=ig_embed" style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px;" target="_blank"> Selena Gomez</a> (@selenagomez) on <time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2018-08-18T20:20:56+00:00">Aug 18, 2018 at 1:20pm PDT</time></p></div></blockquote> **<script async defer src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>**
```

2. Also I changed the src of the script from

```html
<script async defer src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
```

to

```html
<script async defer src="http://www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
```

3. Also I inserted the script code inside index.html at the bottom:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

    <!-- Instagram -->
    <!-- <script async defer src="http://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script> -->

    <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
    <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

    <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
      It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
      <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

      <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
      <script src="build/main.js"></script>

      <script async defer src="http://www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the problem is that the post is not shown and all I can see is this:

[See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVppY.png)

My question is how can I actually show the post instead of the gray Instagram logo I need the picture/video to be shown like a normal Instagram post.

Comment: I also have the same problem. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @otakuProgrammer I posted the answer. It works for me. Try it and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Try to call this function when the content is loaded:

```
instgrm.Embeds.process()
```

**Edit:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class InstagramProvider {

    constructor() {
        this.insertInstagramScript();
    }

    loadEmbeds() {
        let win = <any>window;
        if (win.instgrm && win.instgrm.Embeds) {
        win.instgrm.Embeds.process();
        }
    }

    private insertInstagramScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('src', 'http://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js');
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create a simple provider to insert the instagram library and load posts. I edit my answer with a sample

Answer (score 0):

```
   removeScript(){
        let fjs = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]

   fjs.parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('instagram-wjs'));

  }
  instagramPosts(){
    ! function(d, s, id){
      let js: any;
      let fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

      if (! d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.setAttribute("onLoad","window.instgrm.Embeds.process()");
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js";

        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
      }
    } (document, "script", "instagram-wjs");
  }

  ionViewWillLoad() {
    this.instagramPosts();
  }

ionViewWillLeave(){ this.removeScript(); }
```

This is the solution that works for me.

Comment: Tried copying the code but it shows an error on the instagramPosts() starting from ! . 

Are you using typescript? I'm not familiar with the function though.

Comment: And is this for a mobile app (native?) or it's using browser. 'cause Mine works for ionic serve. But if I build it on an actual device or the simulator/emulator it doesn't work.

Comment: It's typescript for ionic app. Could u tell be what problem/error it throws?

Comment: An expression of type void cannot be tested for thruthiness. Then if I remove the !. Identifier expected on function(d

Then Left side of comma oeprator is unused and has no side effects. (document, "sciprt"

I've tested revising the function but to know luck on letting it work.